# How to transform a dot graph to json graph?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to use sigma.js to show some DOT graph. But it seems that sigma.js only support json graph format.

Is there some bash tools or javascript module can transform a DOT graph to json graph?

For example from DOT graph:

```js
graph {
 n1 [Label = "n1"];
 n2 [Label = "n2"];
 n3 [Label = "n3"];
 n1 -- n2;
 n1 -- n3;
 n2 -- n2;
}
```

Transfer to JSON graph:

```js
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "n0",
      "label": "A node",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "size": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "n1",
      "label": "Another node",
      "x": 3,
      "y": 1,
      "size": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "n2",
      "label": "And a last one",
      "x": 1,
      "y": 3,
      "size": 1
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "id": "e0",
      "source": "n0",
      "target": "n1"
    },
    {
      "id": "e1",
      "source": "n1",
      "target": "n2"
    },
    {
      "id": "e2",
      "source": "n2",
      "target": "n0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`dot -Txdot_json -ogrpaph.json graph.dot`

See https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html#a:xdot_json

Comment: `sudo apt-get install graphviz` -- To get `dot` tools on your Ubuntu machine, maybe it helps someone.

Comment: the output does not seem networkx-compatible... (`KeyError: 'nodes'`)

Answer (score 6):

If you can use python and install 3 packages ([networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html) and [pygraphviz](http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/pygraphviz-1.4rc1/install.html) and [pydot](https://github.com/pydot/pydot)), here is a short script to convert a dot graph to json graph:

```py
# dot_to_json_graph.py
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262441/how-to-transform-a-dot-graph-to-json-graph

# Packages needed  :
# sudo aptitude install python-networkx python-pygraphviz python-pydot
#
# Syntax :
# python dot_to_json_graph.py graph.dot

import networkx as nx
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph

import sys
import json

if len(sys.argv)==1:
  sys.stderr.write("Syntax : python %s dot_file\n" % sys.argv[0])
else:
  dot_graph = nx.nx_pydot.read_dot(sys.argv[1])
  print(json.dumps(json_graph.node_link_data(dot_graph)))
```

Here is your example, converted to json graph:

```js
{"directed": false, "graph": [["node", {"Label": ""}], ["graph",
{"file": "test.dot"}], ["edge", {}], ["name", ""]], "nodes": [{"id":
"n1", "Label": "n1"}, {"id": "n2", "Label": "n2"}, {"id": "n3",
"Label": "n3"}], "links": [{"source": 0, "target": 1, "key": 0},
{"source": 0, "target": 2, "key": 0}, {"source": 1, "target": 1,
"key": 0}], "multigraph": true}
```

Answer (score 5):

I could not install [pygraphviz](https://pypi.org/project/pygraphviz/#description) both in Windows and Linux, and I've ran in the same problem recently.
networkx now have support to dumping into json more easily, including d3.js formats ([info in this page](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html))

I've come with two workarounds:

**1- Use PyDot**

Likely to be outdated soon! [PyDot](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot) may not be used so frequently now that we have graphviz interface in python.

```
def dot_to_json(file_in):
    import networkx
    from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
    import pydot
    graph_netx = networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.read_dot(file_in)
    graph_json = json_graph.node_link_data( graph_netx )
    return json_graph.node_link_data(graph_netx)
```

**2- Use graphviz Source**

As shown in [this part](http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#using-raw-dot) of the graphviz interface documentation, you can create a graph from a .dot source file.

Comment: Thanks! Tried converting using graphviz, but turns out not all output formats are always supported. dot_to_json worked perfectly though.